# problemas de principiante con Net core y relaciones de entidades (theninclude)

Tags: c#, mvc, asp.net-core, linq, net

que tal tengo el problema de que no puedo relacionar tablas, el problema radica en la consulta, para lo cual tengo lo siguiente.

tengo tres entidades.

```
public class MtoMercados
{
    [Key]        
    public int Id { get; set; }
    [DataType(DataType.Date)]
    public DateTime? FechaRegistro { get; set; }

   public string OficioCAASolIm { get; set; }
    
    public DateTime? FechaCCA { get; set; }
    
    public string OficioDBTSolIm { get; set; }
    
    public DateTime? FechaDBT { get; set; }
    
    public string OficioImEnvia { get; set; }

    [DataType(DataType.Date)]
    public DateTime FechaIM { get; set; }

    public string Descripcion { get; set; }
    
    public string NumeroInvestigacion { get; set; }
    
    public string OficioDBTEnvia { get; set; }
    
    public DateTime? FechaDBTEnvia { get; set; }

    [DataType(DataType.MultilineText)]       
    public string Comentarios { get; set; }

    [DataType(DataType.MultilineText)]        
    public string ComentariosCCA { get; set; }

    [DataType(DataType.MultilineText)]       
    public string ComentariosDBT { get; set; }
    
    public string OficioDBTSolicitaPMR { get; set; }
    
    public DateTime? FechaDBTSolPMR { get; set; }

    [DataType(DataType.MultilineText)]
   
    public string ComentariosPMR { get; set; }

    public bool Estatus { get; set; }

    public bool Eliminado { get; set; }

    public int? MtoEjercicioId { get; set; }

    
    [ForeignKey("MtoEjercicioId")]
    public virtual MtoEjercicio MtoEjercicio { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<MtoProcedimientoMercados> MtoProcedimientoMercados { get; set; }
}

public class MtoProcedimiento
{       

    [Key]
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public int Ejercicio { get; set; }
    public DateTime FechaRegistro { get; set; }
    public DateTime? FechaRecepcion { get; set; }
    public string OficioPeticion { get; set; }
    public string NoLicitacion { get; set; }
    public string Fundamento { get; set; }
    public string Descripcion { get; set; }     
    public string Observaciones { get; set; }
    public int MtoCompaniaId { get; set; }
    public int MtoUsuarioId { get; set; }
    public int MtoTipoCompraId { get; set; }
    public int MtoTipoEventoId { get; set; }        
    public int MtoEstadoId { get; set; }
    public int MtoCaracterId { get; set; }
    public int MtoArticuloId { get; set; }
    public int DetalleArticuloId { get; set; }
    public string Caso { get; set; }
    public string NumeroSesion { get; set; }
    public DateTime? FechaSesion { get; set; }
    public string Comite { get; set; }
    public string SubComite { get; set; }
    public string ReferenciaCompranet { get; set; }
    public string CodigoCompranet { get; set; }
    public bool CompraCovid { get; set; }
    public bool Decreto { get; set; }
    public string EtapaInsabi { get; set; }     
    public int EjercicioId { get; set; }


    [ForeignKey("MtoCompaniaId")]
    public virtual MtoCompania MtoCompania { get; set; }
    
    public virtual ICollection<MtoProcedimientoMercados> MtoProcedimientoMercados { get; set; }
}

    public class MtoProcedimientoMercados
{      

    [Key]
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public int MtoMercadosId { get; set; }
    public int MtoProcedimientoId { get; set; }
    
    [ForeignKey("MtoMercadosId")]               
    public virtual MtoMercados MtoMercados { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("MtoProcedimientoId")]
    public virtual MtoProcedimiento MtoProcedimiento { get; set; }
}
```

ahora bien lo que necesito es tener una relación de de Mercados y ver en que procedimientos se ocuparon, para lo cual hago la consulta de la siguiente manera

```
  var mercado = await dbContext.MtoMercados
                .Include(mercados=>mercados.MtoProcedimientoMercados)
                    .ThenInclude(x=>x.MtoProcedimiento)
                .Where(c => c.Id == Id).FirstOrDefaultAsync();
```

no me muestra ningún error pero al momento de depurar me dice que la entidad MtoProcedimiento no existe, podrian echarme una mano por favor.

Comment: Puedes mostrar el código donde inicializas el DbContext? Cómo le estás indicando al DbContext que existe una relación entre ambas entidades? Veo las propiedades marcadas como `virtual`, pero no veo cómo están configurados en el contexto

Comment: @Arriel No necesita relacionarlos en el contexto, porque usa el atributo ForeignKey. Incluso tampoco necesita este atributo porque los nombres que le puso siguen la nomenclatura de 'Id' para los key y HijoId para su clase relacionada

Comment: Para entender el problema, si haces mercado.MtoProcedimientoMercados -> esto existe. Pero si haces mercado.MtoProcedimientoMercados.FirstOrDefault().MtoMercados esto es igual a null?????